# Current View underlapping UINavigationController's navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am designing a registration page view, **programmatically**, for my app where the user can enter in an image of themselves and some info.

In my LoginController I create a UINavigationController with a rootviewcontroller of my RegisterController which is then displayed.

```
func handleRegisterButtonClicked() {
    let registerController = RegisterController()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: registerController)
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Right now I have added a picture for them to click to upload their photo. I want this picture to always show up 30px underneath the navigation bar, but instead underlaps the navigation bar, showing up 30px from the top of the screen:

[Portrait Orientated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFYx4.png)
[Landscape Orientated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBXKT.png)

```
class RegisterController: UIViewController {
...
func setupViews() {
    profilePic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
}
```

Is there a way to add a constraint to the profilePic so that it is anchored to the bottom of the navigation bar (in both portrait and landscape orientations)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of `view.topAnchor` try `topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor`. This should pin it to the bottom of the navigation bar (the view controller’s “top layout guide”).

```
func setupViews() {
    profilePic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
}
```

### iOS 11 or later

In iOS 11 `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` are deprecated in favor of `safeAreaLayoutGuide` (which is a `UIView` property, not `UIViewController`).

If your app will support iOS 11 you should do the following:

```
func setupViews() {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        profilePic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    } else {
        profilePic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    }
}
```

If/when your app only supports iOS 11 or later you can remove the conditional availability check and just go with the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` version.

Comment: Interesting... I wonder how Interface Builder handles this. I guess if you have deployement target of iOS 10.x or lower, IB lets you set up constraints against layout guides just like until now (and no deprecation warnings whatsoever), but if your on iOS 11 or above, IB's UI displays "Safe Area Top Layout Guide" or something like that?

Comment: @NicolasMiari According to this article it seems like IB automatically handles which type of layout guide to use and has a checkbox to adopt the safe area layout guides. https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by making the nav bar not translucent:

In RegisterController, try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to also disable the `edgesForExtendedLayout` property for a given view controller.

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```